# Google Cloud Storage api (c#) - cache header metadata

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

I upload to google cloud storage bucket via the storage c# api (Google.Cloud.Storage.V1). These are public files accessed by client pages.

**Problem:** 
the files are sent with "private, max-age= 0".

**Question:**
I would like to set custom cache headers instead while or after uploading the files via the api itself. Is this possible to sent the cache header or other metadata via the c# google storage api call?

I am also curious: since I have not set any cache header, why does google storage serve these files with max-age=0, instead of not sending any cache header at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the cache control when you call `UploadObject`, if you specify an `Object` instead of just the bucket name and object name. Here's an example:

```cs
var client = StorageClient.Create();
var obj = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object
{
    Bucket = bucketId,
    Name = objectName,
    CacheControl = "public,max-age=3600"
};
var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world"));
client.UploadObject(obj, stream);
```

You can do it after the fact as well using `PatchObject`:

```cs
var patch = new Google.Apis.Storage.v1.Data.Object
{
    Bucket = bucketId,
    Name = objectName,
    CacheControl = "public,max-age=7200"
};
client.PatchObject(patch);
```

I don't know about the details of cache control if you *haven't* specified anything though, I'm afraid.

Comment: From trial and error, "if you if you haven't specified anything" it defaults to 1 hour.